# How to display permission dialog without going back to app

Tags: java, android, permissions, overlay, homescreen

I want to display the permission dialog without going back to my Activity [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77LlG.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF5eT.jpg)

I tried asking AI but it said that I cannot display it I develop an app that captures screenshot

here's the permission code

```
public void requestRecordingPermission() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override

            public void run() {

                mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);

                Intent screenShot = mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent();

                startActivityForResult(screenShot, 30);

              

            }

        }).start();

    }
```

here's my Activity result

`

```
    if (requestCode == 30 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        mediaProjection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);

    }`
```